# Popup element when clicking and hide on HTML click

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML code:

```
<a href="#language">English</a>
<div class="popup" id="language">
  Portuguese | English | French
</div>
```

I want to open / close the div when I click the link.

But I also need the following behavior:

1 - When I click somewhere outside the link the popup should hide.

2 - When I open a Popup I want any currently open popup to close;

I tried the following:

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
});
$("html").click(function (event) {
  $("div.popup").hide();
});
```

But the HTML part makes my code to stop working.

Here is an example: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/sAeEJ

How can I solve it?

Thank You,
Miguel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the event propagation

```
$('a').click(function (event) {
    $($(this).attr('href')).toggle();
    return false;
});
$("html").click(function (event) {
    $("div.popup").hide();
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/DKuFZ/)

Comment: I see ... I though "return false" and "preventDefault" were two ways of doing the same thing. Is it possible to be sure that only one popup is open. I updated my example: http://codepen.io/mdmoura/pen/sAeEJ. Now by clicking the two links I can have the two popups opened. I would like to close all popups when I open a new one.

Comment: @MDMoura no they are not.. `return false` ==  prevent default & stop propagation

Comment: I see. Thank you ... I just solved the other problem. I added $("div.popup").hide(); to a click before the toggle. Thank You

Comment: Oops to fast ... Now the toggle stopped working. Does anyone knows how to solve this?